# No sound Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / 14.10

Tags: 14.04, sound, 14.10, bios

Not been having much luck with ubuntu. At first I installed 14.04, however my display frequently became corrupt or the screen would completely freeze forcing me to restart regularly. These problems were solved when I upgraded to 14.10, however in both cases I've had no sound output.

I've tried many solutions on the web, however they either don't work or lead to other problems. Sound aside, as I boot I'm alerted that I'm doing an "insecure boot" even though I have ""secure boot" enabled in my bios.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte G1 Sniper M5. I can't find audio drivers for the linux platform, but I assume they would be included with the install as the other drivers are.

I'm quite new to the linux terminal, but any help to get this solved would be greatly appreciated! thanks :)

UPDATE: I've continued searching - still no solution found.